# "Invalid security token" while using urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I am trying to get the content of a http request using a python script. But I am receiving 
`Invalid security token` error while executing it.
Here is the following snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2

username="username"
password="password"
url='some_url'
def encodeUserData(user, password):
    return "Basic " + (user + ":" + password).encode("base64").rstrip()
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/json")
req.add_header('Authorization', encodeUserData(username, password))
# make the request and print the results
print res.read()
```

Username and password has special characters.

Comment: `.encode("base64")` is no text encoding. Could you explain what you are trying to do with the function `encodeUserData` ?

Comment: I am trying to encode my user name and password

Comment: You can follow this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html and just need to make your words as byte: `base64.b64encode(b'username' + b":" + b'password')`. Is this helping you?

Comment: @giosans I guess I am doing something wrong otherthan the encoding stuff. It is not working.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Here's the header

Comment: `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Host: <host_url>
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36`

Comment: @sriramsm04 Right. I suggested that because the invalid security token makes me think about auth issues, therefore this bit `encodeUserData(username, password)`.

Comment: @giosans `curl -H "Authorization:Basic <token>" - X GET "<url>" ` 
I am able to do this in bash. Can you help me out with a python script? I have tried both `requests` and `urllib2` modules.

Comment: @sriramsm04 I did the same in curl and python and all options work for me, which I wrote as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you are able to successfully run the request with `curl` on bash, and get `<Response [200]>`, you should be able to run it in python-2.7 with both requests and urllib2. In fact, I just tried and the following works for me:

```
# with requests
import requests
username="username"
password="password"
url='https://url.html'
def encodeUserData(user, password):
    return "Basic " + (user + ":" + password).encode("base64").rstrip()

response = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': encodeUserData(username, password)})
print response.content
```

If you want to use urllib2, this also works.

```
# with urllib2
import urllib2
username="username"
password="password"
url='https://url.html'
def encodeUserData(user, password):
    return "Basic " + (user + ":" + password).encode("base64").rstrip()

req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Authorization', encodeUserData(username, password))
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print res.read()
```

If this does not work, I would suggest you to substitute username and password with the encoded line directly, and see if that would work.